# Sort Field in Pie Charts

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, graph

I'm working on a class project where we make a pie chart out of an attribute table.  The attributes are geologic layers (UNITNAME), and the area they occupy (area_pct).  In the "Create Graph Wizard", I have selected the correct table, and set the value field to "area_pct" and the label field to "UNITNAME".  However, I can't get the sort field to let me select anything.  I want the sort field to be "UNITNAME" as well.  I managed to get it to work yesterday by goofing around with the options, but I honestly have no idea how I did it, and now I can't replicate it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Is this arcGIS (10.2.1) just being picky as usual?

Comment: From what I understand, you want to sort the pie chart based on a text field? I believe the sort field must be a numeric value, so that It can be ascending or decending

Comment: That makes sense to me.  Except that I got it to sort by UNITNAME once, so I know that somehow it is possible.  What I wound up doing is ignoring the sort field, generating the pie chart, and then going in to Advanced Properties - Data, and manually entering the attribute names.  Luckily for me, there were only 6.  If anyone did a pie chart similar to this, but with many sections.... it would become a hassle.